# Set custom profile picture for a contact in Telegram

Tags: contacts, profile, telegram

Is it possible to set a custom image for a contact who may has or not has a profile image in Telegram?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

currently its not possible but you can suggest it to telegram group.

***UPDATE***
Its not what you want but you can create a group and add your friend then change the group profile picture.